redirect URL with query string to URL without query string
I have recently migrated from asp.net website to wordpress.
My old urls look like this
domainname.com/heating-cooling-new-york-city.asp?tn=Washington%20Heights

I want to redirect this url to
domainname.com/heating-cooling-nyc/washington-heights

I wrote the following code in htacess file
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)tn=Washington%20Heights%20NY(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^heating-cooling-new-york-city.asp$ https://domainname.com/heating-cooling-nyc/washington-heights/ [L,R=301]

but its passing the query strings at the end and the final URL is like this
https://domainname.com/heating-cooling-nyc/washington-heights/washington-heights/?tn=Washington%20Heights%20NY

How to redirect to this URL domainname.com/heating-cooling-nyc/washington-heights?

Thanks a lot. Your code for discarding the string worked like a charm.
You missed this in the code without quotes "^(.)" in the following code. RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.)tn=Washington%20Heights%20NY(.*)$ [NC]
Finally the final code looks like this that worked for me
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)tn=Washington%20Heights%20NY(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^heating-cooling-new-york-city.asp$ https://domainname.com/heating-cooling-nyc/washington-heights[L,R=301,QSD]

